# Three out of Six CAS servers do not have group metrics

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I have six Exchange 2010 CAS servers, one of which generates the OAB and Group Metrics.
The server that generates the metrics has a share with the files required.

Our users connect via a load balancer and some of our users noticed that sometimes when sending mails to specific groups that the large audience mailtip was not being generated.

Looking at the client access servers I can see that three out of the six do not have the bin, xml and changedgroups.txt file present in the ClientAccess\GroupMetrics directory.

The file distribution service is running on all servers, and as a test was restarted but still none of the metric files are copied/created to these three servers.

I've been searching online the logs etc but I cannot find the reason for why the files are not present in three of the servers.

They are part of the groups who have permission to access the metrics share on the generating server, and the share can be opened on each of the servers using the unc path.

Has anyone seen similar and how did you resolve it, or can suggest logging etc for troubshooting

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2010 has been ended of support, it's suggested to update your server to Exchange 2016/2019/online ASAP.

The Mailbox server generates full group metrics data for all distribution groups and dynamic distribution groups every sunday and incremental updates for any groups that were modified since the last full generation.The day of the full group metrics data generation is fixed, but you can configure the time it is generated daily. By default, group metrics data is generated daily at a random time within two hours of midnight.
You can try changing the time by powershell:

```
Set-MailboxServer –Identity “servername” -GroupMetricsGenerationTime 01:00
```

If restarting the service not work, try the following command and check the file path:

```
Update-FileDistributionService –identity “servername”
```

You can also try re-creating the arbitration mailbox that generates OAB: https://telnet25.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/arbitration-mailbox-exchange-2010-and-2013/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answer.

In my case the servers were listed as hosting the OAB, but for some reason the group metrics were not present.

I removed and re-added the three problem servers and after running the update-filedistributionserver command the group metrics were replicated.

Have been observing for just over a week and they are now updated daily on the three problem servers as well as the three servers where they were updated already.